# How do I find the length of part of a line segment that crosses a polygon boundary?

Tags: line, sql, spatial-join, sql-server, boundaries

I have a street centerline table and a borough boundary polygon table.  I want to select any centerlines that cross borough boundaries and also return the how much of that centerline is crossing each boundary.  So if a centerline is 100 feet long and 5 feet is crossing the boundary, return that 5 feet in a separate field.  I'm currently using this query to select centerlines that cross:
`SELECT  CL.SEGMENTID as CLSEGMENTID ,CL.SHAPE ,PS.GEOM FROM Centerline_evw as CL JOIN psapboundary as PS ON CL.SHAPE.STCrosses(PS.GEOM) = 1`

Comment: You need to grab the `st_intersection` of the polygon and centerlines, then take the `st_length` of the intersection.  If you're using a geographic coordinate system like 4326, the length units will be degrees, so convert to geography when you do the length `st_length(geom::geography)` - these are postgis functions but you should have similar in sql-server

Comment: Thanks @jbalk I figured it would be something combined with ST_Length.  I think I'm getting close but it's returning centerlines that lie on the polygon boundaries.  Maybe some kind of buffer to filter these records out.  This is what I'm currently using:                    WITH A AS (
SELECT 
CL.SEGMENTID as CLSEGMENTID
,CL.SHAPE AS CLSHAPE
,CL.SHAPE.STIntersection(PS.GEOM) as CLIntersection
,PS.PSAP_AVCARD_URI as PSID
,PS.GEOM
FROM Centerline_evw as CL
JOIN psapboundary as PS
ON CL.SHAPE.STCrosses(PS.GEOM) = 1
)
SELECT A.CLSEGMENTID, A.CLIntersection.STLength() FROM A

Comment: Try adding shape.sttouches = 0.  This will exclude lines that don't go into the interior of the polygons.